# Wordpress URL rewrite regex

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, regex

I'm having trouble trying to learn how to write this url into a regex template to add in as a rewrite. I've tried various regex sandboxes to figure it out on my own but they won't allow a '/' for instance when I copy an expression from here for testing: [image]

I've got a custom post type (publications) with 2 taxonomies (magazine, issue) which i'm trying to create a good looking url for.

So after many hours i've come here to find out how I can convert this

```
index.php?post_type=publications&magazine=test-mag&issue=2016-aug
```

to a templated regex expression (*publication*, *magazine* and *issue* are constant) that can output

```
http://example.com/test-mag/2016-aug/
```

and hopefully with room to extend if an article is followed through from that page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the built in `page` post type rules already capture that particular pattern, you will break any `page/sub-page` requests. this is why custom post types are prefixed with a unique slug.

Comment: But the post type and those 2 taxonomies can be called explicitly.

Comment: Not sure what that means. Rewrite rules are for translating incoming requests into the correct query vars to generate a successful main query. There's no way for WordPress to differentiate `test-mag` or `2016-aug` from `some-random-page` and `some-random-subpage` just from the URL alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wordpress documentations - https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

> **Using %category% with multiple categories on a post**
>
> When you assign multiple categories to a post, only one can show up in
>   the permalink. The categories are ordered alphabetically. In each
>   group of sub-categories the order will also be alphabetical. (see
>   Manage Categories). The post will still be accessible through all the
>   categories as normal.

You can however reach what you want by creating a page with the slug `listpublications` and adding the folllowing code:

```
add_action('init', 'rewrite');
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');

function rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule('listpublications/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=listpublications&magazine=$matches[1]&issue=$matches[2]','top');
}

function query_vars($query_vars) {
    $query_vars[] = 'magazine';
    $query_vars[] = 'issue';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Now go to settings -> permalinks and click save. This will add the new rewrite rules, so this is **very important**.

Now create a template file in your theme folder named `page-listpublications.php` and add the following code between the footer and header.

```
 global $wp_query;

    $query_args = array(
    // show all posts matching this query
        'posts_per_page'    =>   -1,
    // show the 'publications' custom post type
        'post_type'         =>   'publications',
        // query for you custom taxonomy stuff
        'taq_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  =>   'magazine',
                'field'     =>   'slug',
                'terms'     =>   $wp_query->query_vars['magazine']
                ),
            array(
                'taxonomy'  =>   'issue',
                'field'     =>   'slug',
                'terms'     =>   $wp_query->query_vars['issue']
                )
            )

        );

   //fetch results from DB
    $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    if ($query->have_posts()):  while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); 
     // do something sweet with the results
    the_content();
```

Visiting `www.yourdomain.com/listpublications/test-mag/2016-aug` should give you all publications in test magazine and in issue 2016-aug.

Hope this helps :)